# Is Surface 2.0 SDK still being used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pixelsense

I am trying to make an application that will be used on an MS Surface tablet and tried to create a Surface project on VS 2015. When I found that a Surface project is not part of the installed templates in VS 2015, I tried to download the SDK only to find out that it requires VS 2010 in order to use it. After noticing this, I'm starting to think that the Surface 2.0 SDK is no longer being used, but I wanted to make sure before I start looking for an alternative. If that is the case, what other types of templates could be used to create apps for MS Surface tablet?

Comment: I believe the Surface 2.0 SDK was for the table sized Surface device (the tablet borrowed the name from an existing device). Is that what you're targeting or just a Windows tablet?

Comment: Just a windows tablet

Comment: In that case you can just write a Windows 8 or later app.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you have any suggestions on which template to use?

Comment: Any of the Universal templates should work - pick the one that matches the kind of app you're creating. I usually pick the simplest and add what I need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99847/discussion-between-user3344076-and-brian-rasmussen).

Answer (score 2):

As of now it would make more sense to just write a Windows Universal App if your targeting a Windows 8 tablet. This is available in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

It's very confusing of Microsoft to have done this, but the big multi-user table-top devices that used to be called Surface, are now called PixelSense, and the Surface name now applies to a line of touchscreen-enabled laptop computers. [This technote](https://web.archive.org/web/20170710062827/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692162(v=surface.10).aspx) attempts to explain this.

I wasted a LOT of time with this confusion, and hope to spare others.

Comment: This link is dead

Comment: @ChrisZeh: Replaced with an archive.org link.